# How use 2 audio players and stop one when other is playing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-audio

So i have one `audio` player in my page with two play buttons, and i need to stop and play the `player` works with this two buttons.

I'm using html5 and js/jquery for do this, but i can't finding a way to stop audio-player 1 when i start audio-player 2, someone can help?

**My jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/LqM9D/9/

Comment: for now you have only one player on the page

Comment: @falinsky  sorry i explained wrong, I have a player, and 2 buttons for activate it

Comment: so why you want to use two separate buttons to control one player?

Comment: @falinsky well i have the player in header of a page, and when the user is reading an article for example, they can stop and play the audio in the sidebar that looks like those social scrolling sidebar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just use one class name for each button and control them at one time

```
<button class="player-control" id="playpause">play</button>
<audio id="player">
    <source src="http://96.47.236.72:8364/;" />
</audio>
<!-- here the other button that needs to start sound too -->
<button class="player-control" id="playpause2">play</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.player = $('#player')[0];
$('.player-control').click(function () {
    if (player.paused) {
        player.play();
        $('.player-control').html('pause');
    } else {
        player.pause();
        $('.player-control').html('play');
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

My 2cents, it will detect with button is clicked, and change the other one's text back to "play"

```
window.player = $('#player')[0];
$('#playpause, #playpause2').click(function () {
    if (player.paused) {
        var second_playbutton = ($(this).attr("id") == "playpause")
          ? "playpause2"
          : "playpause"
        $("#" + second_playbutton).html("play");

        player.play();
        this.innerHTML = 'pause';
    } else {
        player.pause();
        this.innerHTML = 'play';
    }
})
```

Comment: What does it do? Code without explanation doesn't bring understanding.

Comment: @htatche really. in your solution buttons are not sync.

Comment: @falinsky Because they don't have to, read the question again.

Comment: @htatche Read comments below questions - and you'll understand.